# How to tell thunderbird to display HTML messages?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, thunderbird, email, html

I am running a completely updated and upgraded Lubuntu 14.04. Since some days, Thunderbird stopped displaying certain HTML messages, for example a message that begins with this:

```
------=_Part_12645380_881079428.1428255895880
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org=
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8" />

<meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=3D1.=
0"/>

<title>eBay&trade;</title>

<style id=3D"DS3Style" type=3D"text/css">
```

What to do? I have found nothing about this problem on the Mozilla help site. Is it (L)ubuntu specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

**View => Message Body As => Original HTML**

[image: Menu]

Comment: There is no "View -> Message Body As" path/tab/menu in my Thunderbird 31.6.0, at least not in (my) German version.

Comment: @ubuplex you have to hover with your mouse the top bar (near the X button, where you close the window) in order to see the additional menus. I have attached a screenshot in the answer.

Comment: Solved! I misunderstood you. Thought I had to look under the "Edit -> Settings" menu (or however it is named in English). I cannot understand how none of the three buttons could be activated. I did not change it,  I am sure. Thank you!